# OpenGL - linking glew and glut libs and dlls with g++

Tags: opengl, dll, g++, glut, lib

I have literally spent 5 hours trying to get OpenGl code to compile with g++.

I have tried so many things i cannot even remember to post here.

I guess my problem is linking the .libs and .dlls with g++.

I have placed all the libs and dlls for glew and glut in a folder called lib.
The last thing i did is issue this command:

```
g++ -I./include mytest1.cpp -L./lib
```

Still it didn't work. Any help please?

EDIT:
I am on windows. I don't think i am using FreeGlut, the file name is glut32.dll and glut32.lib

This is the compiler errors:

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined
reference to `_imp____glewDeleteVertexArrays'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewDeleteBuffers'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x127): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x163): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x19f): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x1c3): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x206): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x221): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefine
d reference to `glDrawElements@16'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x26d): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefine
d reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x2af): undefine
d reference to `glFlush@0'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x3e6): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x434): undefine
d reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x581): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x5cf): undefine
d reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x633): undefine
d reference to `glViewport@16'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x68e): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x718): undefine
d reference to `glClearColor@16'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x833): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGenVertexArrays'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x84e): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x906): undefine
d reference to `initshaders(unsigned int, char const*)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x91f): undefine
d reference to `initshaders(unsigned int, char const*)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x93b): undefine
d reference to `initprogram(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x945): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x966): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x987): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x9d5): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xa61): undefine
d reference to `glutInit'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xa6d): undefine
d reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xa81): undefine
d reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xa95): undefine
d reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xaa1): undefine
d reference to `glutCreateWindow'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xaa6): undefine
d reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xabc): undefine
d reference to `_imp__glewGetString@4'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb05): undefine
d reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb11): undefine
d reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb1d): undefine
d reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb29): undefine
d reference to `glutMouseFunc'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb35): undefine
d reference to `glutMotionFunc'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb3a): undefine
d reference to `glutMainLoop'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\U
ser1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc219WZV.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.text$_ZS
t4sqrtf[__ZSt4sqrtf]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT2: Contents of lib folder:

[image]

EDIT3:

Architecture: 64-bit x64

Compiler details (g++ -v):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m
ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l
ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm
p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --
with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-
libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/
mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

The files were downloaded from an edx course on OpenGL. It used Visual Studio, but i cannot use it because my pc is old and i have driver issues, thus i am trying to compile everything from the command line

Comment: Adding some information about your setup (OS and compiler version, used 'glut' etc.) would be helpful. From the text we might only guess you are on Windows system and use the MinGW or msys/msys2 toolchain, but you might also use Cygwin. The library file format for GCC is '.a', not '.lib', so you might need to compile the FreeGLUT and/or GLEW or use the 'dlltool' to generate the export files for GCC.

Comment: I will edit the question. Thanks for yout time.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the GCC to look for libraries and headers in specific folders, but you do not tell GCC to actually link the libraries to the output binary (Imagine having a couple of gigabytes of compiled libraries in a 'lib' folder. GCC or any other C/C++ compiler will not attempt to link all the libraries, because some of them can even be incompatible or contain multiple copies of the same code).

At the very least you should run the

```
g++ -I./include mytest1.cpp -L./lib -lopengl32 -lglew -lfreeglut -lgdi32 -luser32
```

Here I suppose you are using more or less modern version of FreeGLUT.

The '-lSomeLib' assumes you have the 'libSomeLib.a' file in your library folder.
E.g., the '-lopengl32' attempts to link the libopengl32.a file (which is a system library, at least in the MinGW package). The gdi32 and user32 are just the libraries mandatory for WinAPI programs.

There is a [dlltool mini HowTo](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries) which explains how to create the 'libglew.a' file from your 'glew32.dll', but regarding the 'glut32' I suppose you have a problem, because this might be non-compatible with your GCC, so you will have to google for FreeGLUT as an alternative (older GLUT didn't suppor modern extensions, which you are trying to use with GLEW).

To sum up the required steps:

1. Get the correct FreeGLUT library sources or a precompiled 64-bit (!) .dll
2. Get the sources for GLEW (it is a small library, you can compile its sources file by file) or download the 64-bit version of GLEW (I don't think your precompiled glew is 64-bit, you can check this with CFF Explorer tool from ntcore.com). Then compile GLEW or generate the export .a file for your .dll.
3. Add -lglew and -lfreeglut once you have the libglew.a and libfreeglut.a files.

I know this is a long way to go, but in the end it works. Good luck.

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lglew
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lfreeglut
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: So, what are the exact contents of the 'lib' folder ? You can attach the file list (if it's not that large) to the question.

Comment: Another thing is where did you get the lib files ? The problem is now obvious - you do not have a GLEW export library file (I mean, the valid library file for your GCC compiler). By the way, what is the target architecture. Is it 64-bit x64 or 32-bit x86 ?  The 'gcc -v' can tell you the compiler details. This should have been attached to the question also.

Comment: I will add it as a picture

Comment: Everything you asked is added to the question. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I saw the edited question. If i get Freeglut then i am fine, or the code will have to change as well? also, the process you described witht he mini dll tool, do i have to do the same thing for FreeGLUT?

Comment: @user1584421: If your library is called `glut32.lib`, then use `-lglut32`. If your glew library is called `glew32.lib` then use `lglew32`.

Comment: Tried this: 'g++ -I./include mytest1.cpp -L./lib -lglew32 -lglut32' but still nothing.

Comment: GCC will not link .lib files, only .a - for this you have to compile the libraries yourself.